# Ruby: How do I handle time zone offsets that include minutes

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have created an API endpoint that accepts a parameter called `time_zone`. I use this parameter to determine what time zone the requesting user is in. `time_zone` is a utc offset value that should be an integer. Example: MST has a UTC offset of -7.

This allows me to insert the passed in `time_zone` in the following line of code:

```
start_time = Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone).beginning_of_day
```

The above works fine when the time_zone value is something simple like `-7`. However, if the time zone offset includes minutes, I run into trouble. Example: Venezuela is UTC-04:30. If I pass in '-430', I get `ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone`.

What value should I be passing into `Time.now.in_time_zone()' to get my example to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I determined that I need to pass a decimal for time zone offsets that include minutes.

So, to address my previous example using Venezuela (UTC-04:30), I can simply pass in the value `-4.5` and that works perfectly.

Similarly, for Nepal (UTC+05:45) I would pass in the value `5.75`.